# How to move Daedalus's blockchain data folder out of AppData?

Tags: daedalus, blockchain, ledger

I'm a newbie with Cardano. Anyone can tell me how to move the Daedalus blockchain data folder from AppData to another drive?

I want to keep my C-drive's space by moving DB to another drive.

Answer (score 3):

## First solution

After installing the wallet, look for the file called `daedalus.bat` inside Daedalus installation directory. Open it and change the following line:

```
-n --db-path ^
```

for anything like this:

```
-n "%APPDATA%\Daedalus\DB Wallet" ^
```

If you've already synced, move the ledger database to the new location.

## Second solution

You can find the second solution [*here*](https://forum.cardano.org/t/storing-the-cardano-blockchain-on-another-hard-drive-flash-drive/3699).

Comment: Sorry, I can't find the daedalus.bat file in my installation directory.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Daedalus\daedalus.bat

Comment: Yes, there's no file in my dir.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use directory junction ( aka. Hard Link).
Stop Daedalus, open and elevated command prompt and type:

```
mklink /J C:\Users\YOURUSER\AppData\Roaming\Daedalus D:\Daedalus
```

YOURUSER = Your Windows User running Daedalus

D:\Daedalus = Your path where you will store the Daedalus folder

In this way you don't have to modify any config file in Daedalus.